# DSPACE - Making an item visible from different collections

Tags: dspace

Is there any way to make an item visible from different collections and avoid having to create on in every collection in DSpace 5.X?

I've been looking in DSpace, but I can't find if it's possible or how to do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you ask is item mapping. As written in documentation:

> The Item Mapper is a tool in the DSpace web user interface allowing
> repository managers to display the same item in multiple collections
> at once. Thanks to this feature, a repository manager is not forced to
> duplicate items to display them in different collections

Have a look at item mapping in DSpace 5.x Documentation
https://wiki.lyrasis.org/display/DSDOC5x/Mapping+Items for details on using it.